# python datetime.striptime throwing value error while parsing PST time zone with %Z

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, strptime

UTC is working for some reason PST is not, %Z is failing for PST. 
string13 = '18:52:31.868 UTC Fri Jan 17 2020\r'

datetime.strptime(string13,"%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y\r")
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 18, 52, 31, 868000)

string12 = '18:52:31.868 PST Fri Jan 17 2020\r'

datetime.strptime(string12,"%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y\r")
*** ValueError: time data '18:52:31.868 PST Fri Jan 17 2020\r' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y\r'

Can someone explain me how to overcome this above issue?

Comment: Could you please format the code inside ``` blocks?

Comment: Time zone abbreviations should not be parsed.  Many (such as CST and IST) are ambiguous.